# Sugarcube make a random image appear

Tags: twine-game-engine, sugarcube

I'm actually trying to do a random image picker to make the game more real.

here is the actual code

```
<<set $randomimage = random(5)>>

[img["home" + $randomimage.jpg]]
```

I'm only an amateur but it seemed logic to do it that way for me but it appears that in chrome my variable $randomimage is undefined. Getting this error:

```
<img src="homeundefined">
```

Comment: That's not PHP though. That's TwineScript, which is based on JavaScript. It just happens that the variables start with `$` just like PHP.

Comment: I know but it's quite similar to php http://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/

Comment: Similar !== same

Comment: When I tried to put "sugarcube" or "twine" as a tag it didn't work telling me I was needing more reputation to create a tag, so I put the langage that was for me the most similar. (I'm not arguing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<<set $randomimage = random(5)>>

[img["home" + $randomimage + ".jpg"]]
```